# sqlalchemy 1.3.23 relationship with imperative mapping

Tags: sqlalchemy, relationship

How to implement a relationship using classic mapping? sqlalchemy version 1.3.23. A simplified version of what I tried:

```
users_table = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("username", String, nullable=False, unique=True),
)

markets_table = Table(
    "markets",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("type", Enum(MarketTypes), nullable=False),
    Column("status", Boolean, server_default="True"),
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False),
)

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, id, username):
        self.id = id,
        self.username = username

class Market(object):
    def __init__(self, id, type, status, user_id):
        self.id = id,
        self.type = type,
        self.status = status,
        self.user_id = user_id

mapper(Market, markets_table)

mapper(User, users_table, properties={"markets": relationship(markets_table, primaryjoin=users_table.c.id == markets_table.c.user_id)})
```

The problem is that I can't get `users_table.c.markets`

I found several questions on this topic on stackoverflow, but none of them could help me

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the mapped property you should do it from the Class and not the Table, so instead of calling it like:

```
users_table.c.markets
```

you should call it like:

```
User.markets from an instance of the user
```

What you were trying was basically accessing a column markets in the user_table which doesn't exist.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is a typo in the text. I tried different options and got confused when copying.